# Multiple box plots from columns and row groups

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

So I'm trying to visualize my data by making box-plots from a group of genes so that for every gene I have different boxes for different strains. Data looks more or less like this:

```
Strain  gene1         gene2      gene3  .   .   .
 A    2.6336700     1.42802     0.935742
 A    2.0634700     2.31232     1.096320
 A    2.5798600     2.75138     0.714647
 B    2.6031200     1.31374     1.214920
 B    2.8319400     1.30260     1.191770
 B    1.9796000     1.74199     1.056490
 C    2.4030300     1.20324     1.069800
 C    1.4829864     5.570571    12.29139
 C    0.7212928     6.070519    11.63530
 .
 .
----------
```

So for this example I would like to get 3 different pictures (one per gene) and each picture should contain 3 boxes (one for each strain). There is probably a nice and easy way of doing this but so far I'm drawing a Blank...

---

Thanks for all the answers / advice it was all really helpful.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/) and [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_%28ggplot2%29/). From the same cookbook: "To make graphs with ggplot2, the data must be in a data frame, and in "long" (as opposed to wide) format.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `ggplot2`.

First we pass your data frame to a long format :

```
library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df)
```

And then :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dfm) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=Strain,y=value)) + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [`lattice`](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html) package is excellent for this kind of grouping. I have always found it easier to work with than `ggplot2`. You can also do it with the old fashioned base R "ink-on-paper-method" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784376/multiple-box-plots-within-one-group/)), although it is a bit more manual.

First you need to reshape the data frame (btw this step is more nicely done with the `reshape2` package that juba suggested, but I'll keep my solution as an alternative).

```
str <- "Strain  gene1         gene2      gene3
 A    2.6336700     1.42802     0.935742
 A    2.0634700     2.31232     1.096320
 A    2.5798600     2.75138     0.714647
 B    2.6031200     1.31374     1.214920
 B    2.8319400     1.30260     1.191770
 B    1.9796000     1.74199     1.056490
 C    2.4030300     1.20324     1.069800
 C    1.4829864     5.570571    12.29139
 C    0.7212928     6.070519    11.63530"

tab <- read.table(con <- textConnection(str), header=TRUE)
tab <- data.frame(Strain=tab$Strain, stack(tab[-1]))

names(tab) <- c("Strain", "Expression", "Gene")
```

Then plot

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(Expression ~ Strain | Gene, tab)
```

[image]

or the other way combined into a single panel

```
bwplot(paste(Strain, Gene) ~ Expression, tab)
```

[image]