# Teechart Multiple box plot for single point

Tags: activex, teechart

Can we plot multiple box polt for single point similar to what we do in bar chart that we have multiple bar at single point.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple BoxSeries, something like the example here:
http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13048&hilit=boxplot

It's a Delphi example, but it shouldn't be very different in ActiveX.

---

UPDATE:

From your comments, I understand you want to have some boxes in different X positions, and probably in groups. here it is a simple example of how you could play with the Positions to achieve the same:

```
Dim nSeries, groupSize As Integer
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim i, aIndex, sIndex, lIndex, tmpX As Integer

  TeeCommander1.ChartLink = TChart1.ChartLink
  'TChart1.Header.Text.Text = TChart1.Version

  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
  TChart1.Panel.MarginTop = 7
  TChart1.Header.Visible = False
  TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Ticks.Visible = False
  TChart1.Axis.Bottom.MinorTicks.Visible = False

  nSeries = 8
  groupSize = 2

  aIndex = TChart1.Tools.Add(tcAnnotate)
  TChart1.Tools.Items(aIndex).asAnnotation.Text = "group 1"

  tmpX = 0
  For i = 0 To nSeries - 1
    sIndex = TChart1.AddSeries(scBox)
    TChart1.series(sIndex).FillSampleValues
    TChart1.series(sIndex).asBoxPlot.Position = tmpX

    If (i + 1) Mod groupSize Then
      tmpX = tmpX + 1
    Else
      If i + 1 < nSeries - 1 Then
        lIndex = TChart1.Tools.Add(tcColorLine)
        TChart1.Tools.Items(lIndex).asColorLine.Axis = TChart1.Axis.Bottom
        TChart1.Tools.Items(lIndex).asColorLine.Value = tmpX + 1
        tmpX = tmpX + 2

        aIndex = TChart1.Tools.Add(tcAnnotate)
        TChart1.Tools.Items(aIndex).asAnnotation.Text = "group " + Str$(((i + 1) / groupSize) + 1)
      End If
    End If
  Next i

  TChart1.Environment.InternalRepaint
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnAfterDraw()
  Dim tmpX As Integer
  For i = 0 To TChart1.Tools.Count - 1
    If TChart1.Tools.Items(i).ToolType = tcAnnotate Then
      With TChart1.Tools.Items(i).asAnnotation
        If i = TChart1.Tools.Count - 1 Then
          tmpX = TChart1.GetChartRect.Right
        Else
          tmpX = TChart1.Axis.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(TChart1.Tools.Items(i + 1).asColorLine.Value)
        End If

        If i = 0 Then
          tmpX = TChart1.GetChartRect.Left + (tmpX - TChart1.GetChartRect.Left) / 2
        Else
          tmpX = TChart1.Axis.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(TChart1.Tools.Items(i - 1).asColorLine.Value) + (tmpX - TChart1.Axis.Bottom.CalcXPosValue(TChart1.Tools.Items(i - 1).asColorLine.Value)) / 2
        End If

        .Left = tmpX - .Width / 2
      End With
    End If
  Next i
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnGetAxisLabel(ByVal Axis As Long, ByVal SeriesIndex As Long, ByVal ValueIndex As Long, LabelText As String)
  If Axis = 3 Then
    LabelText = " "
  End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am looking something like [how-to-plot-multiple-box-plots-in-one-plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427887/how-to-plot-multiple-box-plots-in-one-plot)

Comment: Have you tried the mentioned? You just have to add several BoxSeries. And some values to each one, of course.

Comment: Yeah I tried this by doing this we can add box plot at multiple X- position what I am looking out is to draw box plot sidebyside on a single position on X -axis, similar to Bar chart we can display bars side by side for multiple series.